# How to efficiently use a Session from within a python object to keep tensorflow as an implementation detail?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn

I'm implementing a custom sklearn Transformer, which requires an optimization step which has been coded in Tensorflow. TF requires a `Session`, which should be used as a context manager or explicitly closed. The question is: adding a `close()` method to the Transformer would be odd (and unexpected for a user), what is the best place to close the session? Should I open and close a new session for a every call to `fit()`? Or should I keep it open and leave the `session.close()` to the `__del__` method of the transformer? Any other options?

Answer (score 1):

Don't open a session at each function call, that could be very inefficient if the function is called many times.

If for some reason, you don't want to expose a context manager, then you need to open the session yourself, and leave it open. It is perhaps a bit simpler for the user, but sharing the `tf.Session` with other objects or libraries might be more difficult. Also trying to hide the fact that you are using tensorflow may be a bit vain, as it is potentially incompatible with other libraries also relying on the GPU. (Also the user will need to install tensorflow to use the library, s/he will *definitely* know that you are using it).

So I would not try to encapsulate things that can't or shouldn't (in my opinion) and use a context manager for the `tf.Session` (maybe even using directly a `tf.Session` itself if I don't mind exposing tensorflow, otherwise wrapping it in my own context manager).

Comment: thanks a lot for your input. Maybe requesting the TF Session to be provided by the user is the cleanest way forward.