# Initializing tensorflow session in a class constructor

Tags: python, oop, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

What is the correct way to keep tensorflow session alive between different methods of a class, with variable initialization only at the time of object creation ?
If i initialize within the fit method, then i cant use that learned model later for predict method
currently i am doing this

```
class AlexNet_model:

    def __init__(self):
        self.sess = tf.Session()
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()   
        self.sess.run(init)
```

and then withing the same class i am calling the fit method

```
def fit(self, x, y, num_epochs = 20):
        X, Y = self.create_placeholders()

        Z = self.AlexNet(X)

        cost = self.cost_fn(Z, Y)
        opt = self.optimizer(cost)

        tot_cost = []

        for epoch in range(num_epochs):
            epoch_cost = 0

            mini_batches_X, mini_batches_Y = getRandomMiniBatches(train_x, train_y)
            for i in range(len(mini_batches_X)):
                mb_x = mini_batches_X[i]
                mb_y = np.array(mini_batches_Y[i])
                temp_Z, _, temp_cost = self.sess.run([Z, opt, cost], feed_dict = {X:mb_x, Y:mb_y.reshape(-1, 1)})

                epoch_cost += temp_cost / len(mini_batches_X)

            print('epoch : {0} \t cost : {1}'.format(epoch, epoch_cost))
            tot_cost.append(epoch_cost)
```

Now when i create and object of this class and call the fit method

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
model = AlexNet_model()
model.fit(train_x, train_y)
```

I get this error , saying uninitialized variables

```
FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value beta1_power
     [[Node: beta1_power/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@conv1/bias"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](beta1_power)]]
```

**Note:**
rest of the functions are defined with the class and are working properly

Comment: Is there any particular relation that you are using a class? Couldn't you just define a function and `return sess`

Comment: `def start_session(self):
        sess = tf.Session()
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()   
        sess.run(init)
        return sess`
I was doing this and calling it inside fit method, but then how would i use the same learned model inside predict method ?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/50310515/1735003

Answer (score 1):

You must call `sess.run(init)` after declaring all the variables, right before the learning loop. I'd suggest building the graph in `__init__` and executing the initializer right after it.

Something like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.X, self.Y, self.Z, self.cost, self.opt = self.build_graph()
    self.sess = tf.Session()

def build_graph(self):
    X, Y = self.create_placeholders()
    Z = self.AlexNet(X)
    cost = self.cost_fn(Z, Y)
    opt = self.optimizer(cost)
    return X, Y, Z, cost, opt

def fit(self, x, y, num_epochs = 20):
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    self.sess.run(init)

    tot_cost = []
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        epoch_cost = 0

        mini_batches_X, mini_batches_Y = getRandomMiniBatches(train_x, train_y)
        for i in range(len(mini_batches_X)):
            mb_x = mini_batches_X[i]
            mb_y = np.array(mini_batches_Y[i])
            temp_Z, _, temp_cost = self.sess.run([self.Z, self.opt, self.cost], feed_dict = {self.X:mb_x, self.Y:mb_y.reshape(-1, 1)})

            epoch_cost += temp_cost / len(mini_batches_X)

        print('epoch : {0} \t cost : {1}'.format(epoch, epoch_cost))
        tot_cost.append(epoch_cost)
```

Comment: can you show a small code sample ? just the general flow

Comment: @ShubhamDebnath updated the answer. I actually did something like this, but the session was not shared between fit and predict. I created one graph for training, and another one for inference. And there were two sessions. So in `fit` I build a train graph, and create a train session, then save it to a checkpoint (see tf.train.Saver). Then in predict I create a new session, build graph again, but do not initialize it, and do saver.restore(inference_sess, 'my checkpoint_path').

Comment: And by using different graphs and sessions I mean declaring, for example, in `fit` a graph by `train_graph = tf.Graph()`, then building it under `with train_graph.as_default(), tf.container('train'):`. Then create a session for training `train_sess = tf.Session(graph=self.train_graph)` and `train_sess.run(initializer)` and saving it with `saver.save(train_sess, checkpoints_prefix, global_step)`. To use the model in predict you do almost the same, and after `saver.restore(infer_sess, checkpoint_path)` you can use your trained model (`infer_sess.run()`).

Comment: yeah i tried using saver and restore then i'm getting "did you mean to use reuse = True'" and when i put reuse at fit and predict methods, the predict method just predicts the same value for all input images

Answer (score 0):

you should define your model without giving it defining a graph inside it..instead define the operation you want the model to do and then wraph everything in the same graph. eg:

```
class AlexNet_model:


    def __init__(self):
       self.AlexNet=(imported AlexNet)
        self.optimizer=tf.train.SGD# use full name

    def fit(X):
        output=self.AlexNet(X)
        return output

    def loss(output,labels):
        return  tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.sub(output,label)))# Or your cost function

    def train(loss):
        self.optimizer(lr).minimize(loss)
```

Then main code for training.

```
from tensorflow.contrib.framework import get_or_create_global_step
   with tf.Graph().as_default():
            global_step = get_or_create_global_step()
            model = AlexNet_model()
            X, Y = model.create_placeholders()
            # define operation so that you execute them in a chane of ops
            output =model.fit(X)
            loss = model.loss(output,Y)
            train_op = model.train(loss)
            #train_op when executed, it will calculate the loss, and the loss will call the output
            init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
            reset_op = tf.local_variables_initializer()
            #intialize global and local variables like Placeholders
            sess=tf.Session(graph=graph)
            sess.run([init_op, reset_op])# run init op

            for epoch in range(num_epochs):
                epoch_cost = 0

            mini_batches_X, mini_batches_Y = getRandomMiniBatches(train_x,train_y)
            for i in range(len(mini_batches_X)):
                 mb_x = mini_batches_X[i]
                 mb_y = np.array(mini_batches_Y[i])
                 temp_Z, _, temp_cost = sess.run([train_op], feed_dict = {X:mb_x, Y:mb_y.reshape(-1, 1)})

            epoch_cost += temp_cost / len(mini_batches_X)
```

`
In the previous code,AlexNet() was not defined in the main graph as the one the class AlexNet_Model has,therefore some of the ops were not initialized.

I would recommend you [MobileNet](https://github.com/Zehaos/MobileNet/blob/master/train_image_classifier.py) as best model design for your reference.